# How to connect PGAdmin3 to Cloud66 hosted Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, cloud66

I have a Cloud66 hosted web app and Postgres database (on a dedicated server)

I'd like to connect to the Postgres DB via PGAdmin3 but I have been unable to configure Postgres to accept my connection.

I have added the following line to **pg_hba.conf**

```
host    all             all             86.161.230.162/32       md5
```

I have checked that **postgresql.conf** has the following setting:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Any ideas?

The doubt in my mind is - Am I editing the correct version of these files?  They took me a while to find and now I'm wondering if maybe there not the correct versions.  These files are located in the directory

```
./usr/local/pgsql/data/
```

Advice/guidance all appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

School boy error.

Of course.  Firewall!

Doh.